# Can't import functions from just created file

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I check if a file exists, and if it doesn't exist then I create it, like so:

```
dir = (os.listdir('.'))
if 'my_functions.py' not in dir:
    fdf = open('my_functions.py', 'w')
    fdf.write("""my function code here """)

print(os.listdir('.'))
from my_functions import function1, function2
```

This doesn't work,  I get an error that says "ImportError: cannot import name 'function1'"

Why is this? The print statement prints all the files in the directory, and I can see that my_functions.py is in the directory. If it's there, why can't it import the functions?

I know it's not an issue with the my_functions.py code itself, because if I run it again (after my_functions.py has been created the first time) then it works without issues.

Comment: What makes you write to file? Hope it is an excercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are creating is called `'file_differ_functions.py'`, not `'my_functions.py'`.

Also you should close files after you open them with `fdf.close()`

Comment: Thanks! .close() fixed it!

Comment: The name issue was just me trying to make my question more generic for SO so it wasn't reflected in the actual code but thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Could be because you have not closed the file, do `fdf.close()` right after `fdf.write` and see if that fixes it.

Or even better use the following format:

```
with open('my_functions.py', 'w') as fdf:
    fdf.write("""my function code here """)
```

And you won't have to close it